# Increasing value, decreasing amount

Tags: terminology

So I really only came here for one question, since I have no idea what it's called.

Let's use a comparison to make it a bit easier.

- I have two coins of the value '1'.
- When I add those together, I get one coin that is worth '2'.
- When I add two of *those(2)* together, I get a coin that is worth '3'
- Ect. Ect.

I realize it might not be the greatest question ever, but what is counting/adding like this called? And is there a formula to easily calculate how many of the coins worth '1' I need to make a coin worth 'X'?

Thanks in advance, and forgive me for asking a possibly easy to answer question.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance it takes $2^{n-1}$ coins of value 1 to get a coin of value $n$. You might say that the coin values combine logarithmically, but that wouldn't be totally clear unless you give the explanation you already did.

Comment: So n would be the value X coin, and the result is the amount of value 1 coins I need to get to X?